# Copy other cells if EITHER column has specific text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

In a single sheet wanting to copy D3:N if either B3:B or C3:C = S2.  I'm sure there is a simple formula to do this I am just unable to find it!

Answer (score 1):

- you can solve this easily with **`QUERY`** formula:

  ```
  =QUERY(D3:N; "where B='"&S2&"' or C='"&S2&"'"; 0)
  ```
- if **S2** cell is a number then it would be:

  ```
  =QUERY(D3:N; "where B="&S2&" or C="&S2; 0)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try a formula like the following:

```
=FILTER(D3:N,(B3:B=S$2)+(C3:C=S$2))
```

Since FILTER conditions are treated as ANDs, using in your two conditions directly would only let rows through if B3:B AND C3:C matched S2. Instead I use a plus sign to add TRUEs and FALSEs since that works as the Boolean OR we need.

Here's the above formula showing matching rows starting in V3:[image: screenshot of Sheets file with columns D to N replicated in V to AF, but only for rows where B or C matches S2.]